# Unable to find "Adobe PDF" resource files on Acrobat DC

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-office-2013, acrobat-pro-dc

For some reason, whenever I try to convert an MS Office file to a PDF (whether Word, PowerPoint, or Excel), I get the error in the title.

This is despite the fact that I can verify the relevant features are installed using the installer.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you're missing some of these files:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\AcrobatPDFMakerForOffice.tlb
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\Fastest.joboptions
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\ImpCommWord.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\PDFMEngine.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\PDFMExcel.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\PDFMOfficeAddin.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\PDFMPowerPoint.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\PDFMWord.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\pdfport.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\Readers
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\Sangam.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\x64
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\Readers\Reader For RTF.smrd
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\Readers\Reader for Word.smrd
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\x64\AcrobatPDFMakerForOffice.tlb
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\x64\ImpCommWord.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\x64\PDFMEngine.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\x64\PDFMExcel.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\x64\PDFMOfficeAddin.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\x64\PDFMPowerPoint.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\x64\PDFMWord.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\PDFMaker\Office\x64\pdfport.dll
```

I fixed this by **removing** and then **adding back** the *"Microsoft Office"* feature under the Adobe PDFMaker feature that pops up when you run the installer (`AcroPro.msi`). Of course you have after you remove the feature so that it gets removed, then run it again to add it back. Furthermore, I added it back by clicking "This feature, *and all its subfeatures*, will be installed", even though no subfeatures were listed. I don't know if the latter made any difference but the issue was fixed for me after these.